British TV show about a widowed football journalist
I saw this TV show in Australia sometime between 1995 and 2005 (I think). It was British, set in Glasgow, possibly a BBC Scotland production.
What else I remember:

I remember it as having four to six episodes, but it's possible it was a telemovie. If there was a second series, I'm unaware of it.
The male protagonist was a football journalist. The few times you saw him doing his job, he'd be at a press conference where the latest Rangers or Celtic signing was being presented and he'd turn the footballer's boring or stupid utterances into something sensible.
He had been recently widowed, his wife having died in a car crash. He was raising their child, a son I think, on his own.
Early in the story he meets the female protagonist. I thought she was played by Dervla Kirwan, but there's nothing on her imdb filmography that matches.
The two meet up somewhere and end up back at his place where they have sex. She gets up the next morning, sees photos of his wife everywhere and mistakenly assumes he's cheating with her. She then paints something like "cheating scum" on the walls of his home and leaves.
He goes to meet her, angrily explains that his wife is dead and then orders her to clean the walls of his house before his kid gets back home from staying with the grandparents, or he'll call the police. Very embarrassed, she complies.

The rest of the story was their relationship developing, I think they get together permanently at the end, but I remember very little about it.

This is Glasgow Kiss (2000).
After seeing wedding pictures of his (dead) wife, his one-night-stand, played by Sharon Small, writes "So long, bastard" on his bedroom wall. He makes her come back and clean it, under threat of calling the police.

Carla Rossi is a business consultant, who has transferred back to Glasgow to downsize the Evening News. On a night out she befriends sports reporter Stuart Morrison, a widower who is looking after his young son, alone.

All six episodes are available on YouTube






@Valorum blimey that was quick! I can't see the youtube link you've posted - stupid geoblocking - but the other details about the graffiti and police are so specific, it just has to be it.

@Moriarty - Something something VPN
